# Java failed to convert int array to Set using Collectors.toSet()

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, hashset

I can't understand the basic thing I have here:

```
 int[] arr = {2,5,2,4,6,6,1,5,4};
        Set<Integer> orederSet  = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.stream(arr).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Side note: also this not working:

```
Set<Integer> orederSet  = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

which gives me compile error:

```
java: method collect in interface java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>
  found: java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.Set<java.lang.Object>>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `arr` is an `int[]`. That means you're calling [`Arrays#stream(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D)), which returns an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html). But none of the primitive stream interfaces<sup>**1**</sup> have a `#collect(Collector)` method. You have to convert the `IntStream` into a `Stream<Integer>`. The easiest way to do that is with the [`IntStream#boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()) method.

```java
int[] arr = {2, 5, 2, 4, 6, 6, 1, 5, 4};

Set<Integer> set =
        Arrays.stream(arr)                  // IntStream
              .boxed()                      // Stream<Integer>
              .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // Set<Integer>
```

As for why the following doesn't work:

```java
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

That's due to `Arrays.asList(arr)` returning a `List<int[]>` rather than a `List<Integer>`.

Neither primitives nor arrays work especially well with generics. Arrays of primitives are worse. A primitive can at least be auto-boxed to the reference type (and vice versa, i.e., unboxed) when appropriate. But primitive arrays have no such special treatment.

---

<sup>**1.** The primitive stream interfaces include `IntStream`, `LongStream`, and `DoubleStream`.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert IntStream:

```
Set<Integer> orderSet = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```